# Find all functions $f$ which are holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and have the property that $z\sin(z)f(z)$ is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $$g(z)=z\sin(z)f(z).$$ As $g$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ and holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ as a product of two holomorphic functions, we can apply Riemann's theorem on removable singularities. So $g$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

Now I believe we need to investigate what kind of singularity $f$ can have at $z=0$.

Comment: $z\sin(z)$ has a zero of order $2$ at $z=0$. So, $f$ can afford having a pole of order up to $2$ at $z=0$. So, $f$ are all the functions of the form $\frac{a}{z^2}+\frac{b}{z}+h(z)$ with $h$ entire.

Comment: Well, Liouville's Theorem implies that $g$ is constant, so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ has either an isolated singularity at $0$ or a pole of order $1$ or $2$ at $0$. Then, near $0$, you have$$f(z)=\frac{c_{-2}}{z^2}+\frac{c_{-1}}z+c_0+c_1z+\cdots$$and, since$$z\sin(z)=z^2-\frac{z^4}{3!}+\cdots,$$the function $g$ has a removable singularity at $0$. So, since it is bounded, it is constant, by Liouville's theorem. And, since $g(\pi)=0$, $g$ is the null function. Therefore, $f$ is the null function.

Otherwise (that is, if $f$ has a pole at $0$ whose order is greater than $2$ or if $f$ has an essential singularity there), then either $g$ has a pole at $0$ or an essential singularity. In either case, it is unbounded.